# Alternating Current having constant magnitude

Tags: electric-current

Most of the sites define alternating current as the electric current that changes magnitude with  time and reverses its polarity periodically.
But magnitude of an alternating current having square waveform does not changes with time.

Is it necessary for an alternating current to vary its magnitude with time?

Answer (score 1):

Most AC sources don't give square wave forms, but cosine, so that's one reason most of the discussion in this topic are of cosine waves. But there is a more fundamental reason: any periodic phenomenon can be described as the sum of cosine waves (See the subject "Fourier Series" for more info on how is that done). So every linear circuit (consisting of linear components like resistors, capacitors, inductors,...) can be analyzed by just analyzing it for a general cosine wave with a certain frequency and then summing up the solutions for your "special" function generator which gives out a square wave, or any other periodic wave form.

This becomes even more fundamental when you consider that every linear system that doesn't depend explicitly on time, won't change the wave form of an input cosine wave, just change its amplitude or phase, making the analyzing of the components even easier.

So does a square wave count as AC? Yes, but there are a couple of reasons to do most of the discussion with cosine waves. Hope this helped!

Comment: I agree with you that sine wave is the most common waveform in electric circuits we deal with  but I just want to say should not we define alternating current as an electric current that periodically reverses its direction and should not comment about variation in its magnitude with time.

Comment: This is a definition question - a good one, but a definition question. I'm not an electric engineer, but I think it is ok to define a square wave as AC (as I said in the answer). But physically, does it matter? [Again, I'm sure this has a good yes-no answer by someone who deals with circuits in his daily life and is more familiar with the definitions, but in my *opinion* this matters less than what is actually happening)